# having trouble with tesseract engine mode on android

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I am brand new to tesseract and OCR in general.  I am working on an android app just to experimenta bit.

I was reading that accuracy can be improved by setting the engine mode:

```
/** Run Tesseract only - fastest */
    public static final int OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY = 0;

    /** Run Cube only - better accuracy, but slower */
    public static final int OEM_CUBE_ONLY = 1;

    /** Run both and combine results - best accuracy */
    public static final int OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED = 2;

    /** Default OCR engine mode. */
    public static final int OEM_DEFAULT = 3;
```

so in my code initiated it like this:

```
 TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang, enginMode);
    Log.v("NUMBER LINES","*************************************************** "+baseApi.getWords());
    baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
   // baseApi.setPageSegMode(baseApi.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED);
    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

    baseApi.end();
```

but if i set `engineMode` to anything besides `OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY` my app crashes and gives the following error:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1);
```

also does anyone know how to reiterate through the results by line or word?

Comment: What language/trained data are you using? Not all languages have data for Cube.

Comment: Hi @erik, Were you able to integrate Cube Engine? If so, can you clarify a bit by providing pointers for the way we need to integrate Cube? Tesseract I am able to do, but find accuracy level low as you commented above. Thanks.